# Showing & Hiding UIButton with Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

How would I go about making this `UIButton` slowly disappear from the view? The animation I'm looking for would make the button look like its widthrawing downward. Should I use `Core Animation`? I'm rather new to iPhone development, but this seems like something that should be doable

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just want to animate the changing of the frame (or precisely, the center position) simply by using UIView's class method `animateWithDuration:animations:`

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:<some duration> animations:^{
    myButton.center = (CGPoint){myButton.center.x, CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame) + (CGRectGetHeight(myButton.bounds)/2.0)};
}];
```

CoreAnimation would be overkill for this simple operation.

Comment: wow this works perfectly, except that I believe you wanted self.view.frame

Comment: also one last question, when I want to animate the button back to its original state, would I just use CGRectGetMaxY - the button height?

Comment: Close. y = `CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame) - (CGRectGetHeight(myButton.bounds)/2.0)`

Comment: ah yes that would make sense, didn't really think that one through. Thanks for this block, it's really eloquent and works perfectly =)

Answer (score 1):

Use UiView and put the button on it... then add animation to the Uiview...What you want

```
   UIView *upwardView=[[UIView alloc]init];
   upwardView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[upwardView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 200)];


UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn setTitle:@"Click me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.frame=CGRectMake(10, 20, 120, 40);
[upwardView addSubview:btn];

CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFade];
[animation setDuration:.50];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
CALayer *layer = [upwardView layer];
[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
[self.view.window addSubview:upwardView];
```

don't forget to  import QuartzCore/QuartzCore framework

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? Could you provide the structure for how I'd go about writing this code, or perhaps point me to a relevant tutorial? I'm just really new to iPhone programming, especially animation...

Comment: if I want this animation to be triggered when the button itself is pressed, would I add the CATransition in the IBAction for the button?

Comment: @BobYousuk make your uiview in viewdid load then on the action of button you can put the CATransition animation and remove the upward from superview

Comment: Vivek, I disagree with your advice. Core Animation is much harder to use than view animation. gschandler's suggestion of using UIView animation seems like a much better fit for this. CA Animation is much more powerful than view animation, but it also much, much harder to figure out.